# Insufficient privileges to list group members in Graph API

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'm building an API which is called by a SPA (angular). The user is authenticated using Azure AD and the API uses AzureAdBearer for its authentication.

I need the backend to call graph api on behalf of the user to list members of an AD Group.

[According to this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), I need one of these permissions:

```
User.ReadBasic.All, User.Read.All, Group.Read.All, Directory.Read.All
```

So I have added User.ReadBasic.All to my api permissions list in the app registration of my backend.
[image: backend permissions]

I used an `IAuthenticationProvider` to handle the authentication using this code:

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("{my client id}")
                 .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my tenant id}")
                 .WithClientSecret({my backend secret})
                 .WithLogging(Log, Microsoft.Identity.Client.LogLevel.Info, true)
                 .Build();

var token = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(token);
var result = await app.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }, userAssertion)
                      .ExecuteAsync();

request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
```

The result is successful, when I check my token using jwt.ms everything seems correct, here is an extract of it:

```
"aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
"iss": "https://sts.windows.net/{my tenant id}/",
[...]
"app_displayname": "My app",
"appid": "{my client id}",
[...]
"scp": "User.ReadBasic.All profile openid email",
[...]
```

However on this call using the GraphApiClient:

```
var client = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var users = await client.Groups["group guid"].Members.Request().GetAsync();
```

I get this error:

```
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This call `var users = await client.Groups["group guid"].Members.Request().GetAsync();` requires a [group permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) (i.e.`Group.Read.All`).

You only have [user permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) right now (i.e.`User.ReadBasic.All`).

Comment: That's what I suspected but wasn't sure. I wanted to be sure before requesting this permission to my azure ad's admin. Thanks

Comment: You can get the groups on a user via the user api if needed... ```GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/memberOf``` or in SDK, ```var usersGroups = await graphClient.Users[id].MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();```

Comment: Also note that `User.ReadBasic.All` is _extremely_ limited. You're going to want `User.Read.All`. Since both `User.Read.All` and `Group.Read.All` require Admin Consent, you should be sure and request both and save some cycles.